# css transition does not work on opacity when adding a class to a element

Tags: html, css

```css
.hide {
    height: 0;

    opacity: 0;

    transition-property: height, opacity;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-duration: 3s;
}

.show {
    height: 40vh;

    opacity: 1;

    transition-property: height, opacity;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-duration: 3s;
}
```

So I have a button where when pressed, it adds the `show` class to a element, if pressed again it adds the `hide` class. I am trying to do a dropdown menu transition, but the problem is that the `transition` for the `opacity` isn't delaying

A video of what I am currently doing: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/244242279865384963/910537915308851270/localhost_3000_reviews_-_Google_Chrome_2021-11-17_22-31-26.mp4

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on writing questions that best enable the community to provide meaningful guidance.  While it is good that you have included your CSS, but we are limited in how much we can understand it without the context of the HTML and JS.  Would it be possible to include a [mcve] that reproduces the issue, preferably as a snippet in the body of the question?  It would be also be helpful to include the steps to reproduce, the expected behavior, and the actual behavior.  Thanks, good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

There is a problem with order of selectors. Class that hides element should be below show selector.

```
.show{
    height: 40vh;
    opacity: 1;
    transition-property: height, opacity;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-duration: 3s;
}
.hide{
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition-property: height, opacity;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-duration: 3s;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```js
const div = $('#hide');
    $('#click').click(() => {
        if (div.hasClass('hide')) {
            div.removeClass('hide');
            div.addClass('show');
        } else {
            div.removeClass('show');
            div.addClass('hide');
        }
});
```

```css
.hide {
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition-property: height, opacity;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-duration: 3s;
}

.show {
    height: 40vh;
    opacity: 1;
    transition-property: height, opacity;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-duration: 3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="background-color:black">
        <button id="click">Click</button>
        <div id="hide" class="hide" style="width: 100vw; background-color: gray; padding: 10px; margin: 0">
            <h3>Some title</h3>
            <p>Some text</p>            
            <footer>Footer</footer>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Write in the comments why you minus the answer!